# Как сделать, чтобы в singleton не работала двойная блокировка?

Tags: java, singleton

Как сделать, чтобы в singleton не работала двойная блокировка?

Comment: Там специфическая архитектура процессора нужна, вроде x86 не использует переупорядочивание команд.

Comment: Какая именно блокировка?

Comment: нужно [много раз запускать](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/#_correctness)